# Why does the HTTP request not throw an error after its set Timeout

Tags: java, http, error-handling

## Some Preamble

I'm writing a program that sends requests out to a webserver that is hosted on a device, if the device has a USB plugged into it then a webpage exists under the `/USB` endpoint and i can read the contents of the USB. From my testing there are 3 states that the device can be in

1. Webserver did not boot up (java.net.ConnectException)
2. USB not plugged into Device (404 Not Found)
3. USB Exists and is readable (200 Success)

## The Problem

Ive written some code such that i can loop through hundreds of devices on multiple threads and check for their USB and Webserver states (see the 3 states above) however I am noticing that my program will get hung up on some of the HTTP Requests shown below is how i am making the `HTTP` request to  the endpoint

```java
InetAddress Address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr);
HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "Basic REDACTED")
                .uri(new URI("http://"+Address.getHostAddress()+"/usb/log/"))
                .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
                .GET()
                .build();
try{
    HttpResponse<String> res = this.Http.send(req, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    System.out.println(res.statusCode());
    if(res.statusCode()==200){
        this.Usb=ConnectionState.NO_PROBLEM;
        this.GetLatestDate(res);
    }
    if(res.statusCode()==404){this.Usb=ConnectionState.NO_DEVICE;}
}catch (HttpTimeoutException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Failed to Connect?");
}catch (ConnectException e){
   System.out.println(e.toString());
   System.out.println("Webserver Did Not Boot Up");
   this.Usb = ConnectionState.NO_DEVICE;
}catch (Exception e){
   System.out.println(this.HmiID + " USB: "  + e.toString());
}
```

What you should notice is that I have `.timeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000))`. From what ive read this should cause the `HttpTimeoutException` to be thrown after5 secconds, however when so in theory each thread shouldn't run longer than lets say 10 seconds (accounting for other logic performed in the thread)

Why then do i have instances of threads running for 151 seconds, or even 482 seconds!?

Am i misunderstanding how the `timeout` works fundamentally?

Comment: Maybe it sets a read timeout only, not a connect timeout.